# python type hints on module properties (like Protocol for module)

Tags: python, python-typing

I have multiple modules that act as a plugin system.
Each module has identical funcions and properties, but different endpoints.

For example, module1.py and module2.py each have a `def go()` and a VALUE_1 constant.

Now I am looking to type annotate this when I would pas a module to a function:

```py
import module1

def do_stuff_with_module(a_module):
    a_module.go()
```

So I guess I am looking for a structural type checker for a module like we have a Protocol for classes. Anyone any idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: You could have a base class (perhaps use ABC) then use that class as the type check since all classes will inherit from it.

Answer (score 1):

look here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/#modules-as-implementations-of-protocols

Guido took care of it..